# java.lang.NullPointerException on show toast

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm using the **OkHttp** library to access a **url**, and I want to display a **Toast** when returned given message. The problem is that when I try to view the **toast**, the `java.lang.NullPointerException` error is displayed. Can you help me?

Sorry for my bad English.

```
public void sendtows(String usr_e, String usr_p) throws Exception{
    String stResponse;

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://127.0.0.1/l.php?useremail=" + usr_e + "&userpassword=" + usr_p)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    stResponse = response.body().string();

    if(response.isSuccessful()){
        if(stResponse.contains("OK")){
            Log.d("Login", "Ok");
        } else {
            Toast toastErr = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toastErr.show();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("ERRO", "erro");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: That toast looks fine. Are you sure that's the origin of the exception?

Comment: Where did you call sendtows this method?

Answer (score 0):

Don't work! The log:

> 09-14 16:47:49.802    4342-4374/com.android.vending D/Finsky﹕ [222]
>   AppStatesReplicator.handleContentSyncResponse: Completed 0 account
>   content syncs with 0 successful. 09-14 16:47:49.802
>   4342-4342/com.android.vending D/Finsky﹕ [1] 5.onFinished: Installation
>   state replication succeeded. 09-14 16:48:08.112
>   2487-2532/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ Motion event has invalid
>   pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16. 09-14 16:48:08.182
>   2487-2532/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ Motion event has invalid
>   pointer count 0; value must be between 1 and 16. 09-14 16:48:08.182
>   1289-1323/? D/audio_hw_primary﹕ found out /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p 09-14
>   16:48:08.242    1289-1323/? W/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_write() limiting
>   sleep time 112539 to 46439 09-14 16:48:08.312    1289-1323/?
>   W/audio_hw_primary﹕ out_write() limiting sleep time 65759 to 46439
>   09-14 16:48:09.652    4227-4227/com.lavie.conflife D/Errorx﹕
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-14 16:48:18.152
>   2657-3291/com.bluestacks.bstfolder D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed
>   740K, 29% free 2774K/3868K, paused 0ms, total 0ms

onClick call the sendtows

```
public void sendData(View view){ //btLogin click
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    if(checkInternetConnection()){
        try{
            usr_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
            usr_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

            final String email = usr_email.getText().toString();
            final String pass = usr_password.getText().toString();

            if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
                usr_email.setError(getString(R.string.invalid_email));
            } else if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                usr_password.setError(getString(R.string.invalid_password));
            } else {
                new LoginActivity().sendtows(usr_email.getText().toString(), usr_password.getText().toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Errorx", e.toString());
        }
    } else {
        CharSequence text = "Offline";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using **getApplicationContext()** in **Toast**, which is **might be** giving you **NullPointerException**. So,

If you are using **Fragment** use:

```
Toast toastErr = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toastErr.show();
```

If you are using **Class** then make a constructor which can pass **Context** and use that **Context** in **Toast** like as below:

```
//Constructor to pass context
 public Your_ClassName(Context context){
      this.context = context;
    }

 Toast toastErr = Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toastErr.show();
```

Comment: getActivity() causes a crash from a Fragment